# Sanity.io reusable schema field types

Tags: javascript, typescript, sanity

I'm new to Sanity.io. I'm just wondering if there is a way that I can optimize my codes and reuse the fields in different schemas.

Im thinking something like this:

cars.ts:

```
export default {
    name: 'cars',
    title: 'Cars',
    type: 'document',
    fields: [vehicleName]
}
```

trucks.ts:

```
export default {
    name: 'trucks',
    title: 'Trucks',
    type: 'document',
    fields: [vehicleName]
}
```

vehicleName.ts:

```
export const vehicleName = {
    name: 'name',
    title: 'Name',
    type: 'string',
    validation: Rule => Rule.required()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    {
  title: 'Vehicle Names',
  name: 'vehicles',
  type: 'array',
  of: [
    {
      type: 'reference',
      to: [
        {type: 'cars'},
        {type: 'trucks'}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

You can use references to access the cars and trucks in as many different schemas as you want making your code reusable

```
export default {
    name: 'trucks',
    title: 'Trucks',
    type: 'array',
    fields: [
    {
      title: 'Names',
      name: 'names',
      type: 'reference',
      to: [{type: 'vechicleName'}]
    }
  ]
}
```

Sanity is bi-directional